# spam asynchronous callbacks breaking my setTimeout delay

Tags: javascript

So my character div changes its background image when the player presses x which then kills the enemy if the character is touching the enemy. This image switch is to do a mock animation of swinging a sword.

I used set timeout to delay switching the background image back to its original state. This works.

**HOWEVER** theirs a bug where if I spam x there is no longer a delay between the images switching and I hypothesize the reason having something to do with stacking asynchronous callbacks from the setTimeout function that gets invoked when the player spams x.

** SET TIMEOUT INVOKED IN THIS FUNCTION **

```
function pressOn(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    let tempKey = (e.key == " ") ? "space" : e.key;
    keys[tempKey] = true;

         if (keys['x'] && player.swing == false){
              player.plane.style.backgroundImage ='url(guts2.png)';
                 setTimeout(function () {
                 player.swing = true;
                 }, 300);
          }

 }
```

** REVERTS BACKGROUND IMAGE TO ORIGINAL **

```
function playGame() {
   if (player.inplay) {

       if (player.swing && !keys['x']){
             player.plane.style.backgroundImage ='url(guts1.png)';
             player.swing = false;
        }

    window.requestAnimationFrame(playGame);
    }
}
```

** LINK TO JS FIDDLE FULL PROJECT **

https://jsfiddle.net/mugs17/sud2ojxy/17/

Comment: Take a look at debouncing, you could prevent the function from being triggered more than once within a certain time frame. It's very useful for preventing input overload.

Comment: It is always good to provide a `jsFiddle` in such cases. That way the people that are going to answer your question would not have to go through the process of copying and pasting everything in JSFiddle in the first place.

Comment: @AFOC Never heard of that, i'll do some research. Thanks :)

Comment: @jsFoddle oh good idea, but Idk if its worth it if I can't upload images to JSfiddle because my project wont work without them :/

Comment: @Mugs you can upload your images to Imgur and then use it with a URL. I don't see the problem you are facing as I can not replicate the entire thing! 

That doesn't mean I don't want to help. It takes time reading through others' code. And I am sure the majority of people answering don't have hours worth of time reading through others' code.

Comment: If possible, please try to include only enough code to produce a demonstration of your issue. As it stands you've posted a pretty big wall of code, however it's much easier to help when your question includes a [**minimal**, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: @Prasanna Okay! Thanks for the help. I set it all up on JS Fiddle. Had no idea you could do that. Really appreciate the advice

Comment: @TylerRoper I moved the file to JS Fiddle and only left the necessary code to understand the problem. You can't really reproduce it without the project though because you need to use elements in the dom and its connected to a lot of other things in the project

Comment: @Amessihel thanks for the tip

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your logic is backward in setTimeout. You want to set swing equal to true automatically (which will prevent the if statement from executing) and inside the setTimeout callback you set it back to false.

### - Heres the solution:

```
let player = {
       swing: false
}
```

-

```
function pressOn(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    let tempKey = (e.key == " ") ? "space" : e.key;
    keys[tempKey] = true;

    if (keys['x'] && player.swing == false) {

        player.plane.style.backgroundImage = 'url(guts2.png)';
        player.swing = true;

        setTimeout(function () {

            player.plane.style.backgroundImage = 'url(guts1.png)';
            player.swing = false;

        }, 1000);

}
```